# Soft Bodies floating up

Tags: physics, soft-body

for some reason, the objects are floating up at the end of the gif. All settings are identical on the objects.
Any Help on how to debug this? I played around with the parameters for some time now but cant find a way to fix it

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: please share your blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I didnt know this. Thanks. I updated the question with the blend file. thanks for looking into it

Comment: I would say its because last two objects penetrates into each other ... try to avoid that.

Comment: worth a try. How could I approach that? I mean they are just falling down on each other. How can I control that they shouldnt penetrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because last two objects penetrates into others ... try to avoid that.

Set *Collision > Thickess Outer* to 0.1

[image]

Also use *Merge by Distance* to clean up your topology, it really matters in this kind of sim :)

Comment: wow. thanks so much. ill try that immediatly

Comment: .1 doesnt mean 10 cm around the object in this case, right?

Comment: hm - now the objects just disappear after dropping a few frames.

Comment: when I set the solver min and max to zero, the objects dont disappear anymore. But is a higher number not supposed to give better simulation?

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. I cleaned the meshes. but setting thickness outer to 0.1 makes it worse. Now the block start floating up even earlier

Comment: With Sims there is a quite often issue with outdated cache ... If you experience unexpected or unusual behaviour, change start frame +/- 1 ... Please avoid chatting in comments, delete unimportant, important info include into your question via Edit. Thank you keep this site organized.

Comment: at the end of the day it worked. it was probably a combination of what was said in the answer here and fiddling around with parameteres